# Show json url to messenger bot

Tags: node.js, bots, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I want to show data from JSON URL on my facebook messenger bot. I've tried with a lot of code approach. However, I couldn't still get it. I just could show the data the terminal with console.log.

This is the code I use to get data from JSON URL:

```
const ambilDataProfil = (sender_psid) => {
//sorry this url below is not valid I write intentionally for my privacy data.
    request({
        url: 'https://sorry-url-privately.firebaseio.com/server/saving-data/users.json',
        method: "GET",
    }, function(error, response, body){
        let jsonBody = JSON.parse(response.body);
        let resp = jsonBody.Ndus;
        console.log(resp);
        let respon = {"text": "resp"};
        callSendAPI(sender_psid, respon);
    }
        // console.log(body.Ndus.goldar);
    );
};


function callSendAPI(sender_psid, response) {
    // Construct the message body
    let request_body = {
        "recipient": {
            "id": sender_psid
        },
        "message": response
    }

    // Send the HTTP request to the Messenger Platform
    request({
        "uri": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages",
        "qs": { "access_token": PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
        "method": "POST",
        "json": request_body
    }, (err, res, body) => {
        if (!err) {
            console.log('message sent!')
        } else {
            console.error("Unable to send message:" + err);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? Is it that the message isn't sending at all? Is it that the JSON isn't formatting properly in the message? Please add more detail to your question.

Comment: @amuramoto I could not show the data I got from JSON to my messenger bot. I just could show the data on console on my heroku